# USING MOD_WSGI with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, mod-wsgi

Inside our web application, we using PHP to with EXEC command to call some python scripts and it is working fine except we found there are always has 3-5 seconds delay when calling it. If run the same python script right inside the IDE and it runs less than a second.

I did some research, it seems is because the python interpreter keeps loading everytime we execute the script from PHP. We would like to eliminate that few seconds delay.

Then I found the Mod_WSGI that comes with Apache may be able to help on it and think that can let us call the python script directly.

Just followed the instruction on https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/
and get the mod_wsgi up an running.

add some line in my httpd.conf as follow and I'm able to run the "hello world" WSGI application from the browser

```
WSGISocketPrefix /var/www/html/public_html/wsgi/
WSGIDaemonProcess myserver_wsgi processes=2 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP}
WSGIProcessGroup myserver_wsgi

    WSGIScriptAlias /wsgi /var/www/html/public_html/wsgi/myapp.wsgi

    <Directory /var/www/html/public_html/wsgi/>
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all
    </Directory>
```

Now, I have no idea how to use the WSGI to call all my python PY scripts. The httpd.conf is pointing to a specific myapp.wsgi, how can I run more than one of those scripts?

Here are my questions.

1. Is that a right solution to eliminate the overhead/delay when running python script through PHP
2. We are using AngularJS framework as front end and PHP as the backend, is that possible to call the python script directly from the JS file? like using the $http service?

If yes, how to do that?

I'm stuck now and only get the WSGI "hello world" working and don't know what to do next,  any ideas and solution are welcome and thank you in advance.

Comment: You cannot call Python code hosted with mod_wsgi from PHP. What you can do is write your web application code handlers in Python instead of PHP and make requests against them from any front end JS code if need be. I would suggest you go read up about a Python framework such as Flask. You should avoid using WSGI directly, use Flask and host it on top of mod_wsgi as Flask docs explain.

Comment: Will take a look what Flask do and I can call it directly from JS?

Comment: I also like to know if the mod_wsgi is the right thing to do to solve our problem about calling the.PY script from PHP causing some delay. I don't want to waste the time if that is not the right solution since the application is running fine using PHP to call Python script.

Comment: In going to something like Flask running on mod_wsgi you are effectively moving to start writing a web service on top of Python, rather than just a single function to do what you want. You may not want to philosophically make such a change.

Comment: thanks, so what should I do to get around my delay problem when calling python script and how to call them in JS directly. It seems no one can give me a clear answer, I'm sure someone out there should be setup like this to run python from their AngularJS application.